# RxJs - How to properly handle an observable if its empty before it is used for a service?

Tags: angular, rxjs, ngrx-component-store

I am capturing the `id$` from the route and I want to check that the observable is not empty, before I pass it to a service when it is needed. Is there a RxJs approach to check if  it is not empty, without subscribing?

```
    id$: Observable<string | null>;        

    constructor(
        activatedRoute: ActivatedRoute,
        private store: Store
    ) {
        this.id$ = activatedRoute.parent!.paramMap.pipe(
            map((p) => p.get('id')),
        );

        combineLatest([this.id$]).subscribe((p) => {
            let id = 0;

            if (p && +p) {
                id = +p;
                this.store.load({ id });
            } else {
                this.store.setStoreStatusTo('error'); // my current way to handle the error
            }
            
        });
    }

    // this is where I want to be sure that id$ is not empty
    sendToService = () => this.store.sendToService(this.id$);
```

Comment: The point of an Observable is that you would `subscribe` to it and the observable will push a value to the subscriber when there is a value to offer. The design here seems fundamentally flawed and counter intuitive to what `Observer` do

Comment: @sinanspd That's right, and I was mistaken to say that I want to implement this, without any subscribing involved. I expect a value to always come thru, but I just want to have a safety net incase anything abnormal happens to the route.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suspect `filter` may do the trick (https://rxjs.dev/api/operators/filter)

so in your case it would probably be

```
this.id$.pipe(
filter(x => x !== undefined)) //or whatever null checking you need to do
.subscribe(x => {...})
```

Comment: ```filter``` wouldn't help me because I want to know if a ```null``` value passes through. Also I only expect a single value emission.

Comment: I suspect it would (?) as in your method for sending you can verify that the id isn't null, and only execute the api call if it is not null, otherwise do nothing or raise an error. This is assuming I understand your desired behavior, as otherwise you will need to subscribe to the observable to get its underlying value

Comment: I will need to subscribe to get the underlying value, that's right. Sorry for the missing context, thank you for your help!

Comment: Instead, pipe `filter(x => !!x)` to the end of `id$` and send it anyway. It won't emit if undefined, null, or otherwise falsy, therefore anything downstream never emits and you don't need to check it first, nor subscribe, until the end of the stream when you actually want to do something with it.